# How to use the search bar to filter my leaflet markers

Tags: filter, leaflet, odoo, odoo-9

I've made a custom view in Odoo to place partners (from res_partner) on a map (via Leaflet). On this map, it place markers with a pop up that show infos related to the partner. (like this picture)

[image]

That good, but I want that when I use the search bar, it filter the markers, to only show those that are relevant.

I'm new to Odoo (so I might ask a stupid question), and we have to use Odoo 9 at work actualy (so we can't use something else).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found out. I just had to use the `do_search` method, and pass the `domain` attribute in my `query().filter()` (like this: `query().filter(domain)`)